# How to run Azure automation runbook in power shell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I am trying to run 'Connect-AzureVM' by importing it from the gallery. But no service or VM are created as I get these errors in job 'History'. The credential 'xyz' and subscription name 'ABC' both exist; I don't know why it's throwing an error.

```
workflow m1
{
    $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "xyz"

    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred

    InlineScript {
       Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "ABC"
       Get-AzureVM | select InstanceName
    }
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Error: System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null

Error: The subscription named 'ABC' cannot be found. Use Set-AzureSubscription to initialize the subscription data.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears $Cred is null in the above runbook. Are you sure you have created the credential "xyz" as an Automation credential asset in the automation account where this runbook is running?

If you add the lines:

```
$CredIsNull = $Cred -eq $Null
Write-Output $Cred
Write-Output $CredIsNull
```

When you run the runbook, what does it output for $Cred and $CredIsNull?

Comment: "xyz" exists as an automation credential asset. I've run this as suggested by you. 
`workflow m1 { $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "xyz" $CredIsNull = $Cred -eq $Null Write-Output $Cred Write-Output $CredIsNull }` 
This is the output: 
PSComputerName : localhost 
PSSourceJobInstanceId : 942707db-d44d-45bf-aa4d-d8ed5b895d9c UserName : xyz 
Password : System.Security.SecureString 
False

Comment: If I add this one extra line at the end of the above script:
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred 

Then in job history of this job I get this:
Error 12/29/2014 1:12:50 PM unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type

Comment: OK, well that is a different error than you were getting before. For whatever reason, $Cred does not seem to be null anymore. Are you sure the credential contained in "xyz" is an OrgID credential? Did you follow the guide here to create this OrgID cred? http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/

Comment: Also maybe this thread will help - this user is getting same error as you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4f5ac38-db33-4082-a3de-b4b8d501b35a/addazureaccount-unknownusertype?forum=azureautomation

Comment: It's working like charm now. The problem was with OrgID credential as you've stated. I was not appending anything after @ to the username in credential. Made it similar to the one created in AD.

Thanks much for your valuable support.